# Trouble connecting to PostgreSQL database using JDBC in Android Studio

Tags: android, postgresql, kotlin

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database using JDBC in my Android Studio project. I've added the JDBC driver to my app's dependencies in the build.gradle file, and I'm using the following code to establish the connection:

#### Error I have catched:

ERROR 2 kotlin.Unit

JDBC driver

#### build.gradle

```
   minSdk = 23
   targetSdk = 34
    dependencies {
        implementation(files("/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/SocWebCash/app/libs/postgresql-42.2.27.jre6.jar"))
      }
```

#### Code

```kotlin
package xcodex_biz.socwebcash.database
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException

fun connectToDatabase(): Connection? {
    var connection: Connection? = null
    println("++++++++++++++++++=checking!")
    try {
        // Load PostgreSQL JDBC driver
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")

        // Database connection parameters
        val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name"
        val username = "postgres"
        val password = "password"

        // Establish connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
        // Log message indicating successful connection
        println("+++++++++++Database connection established successfully.")
    } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        println("################ ERROR 1${e.printStackTrace()}")
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        println("################ ERROR 2${e.printStackTrace()}")
    }
    return connection
}


//Calling Here
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Retrieve emails from the "users" table
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    enter code here
        connectToDatabase()
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are not printing a proper stacktrace for some reason. Maybe just re-throw the errors and you will see what the problem is?